# perl reading file and grabbing specific lines

Tags: perl, file, string-matching

I have a text file and I want to grab specific lines starting with a pattern and ending with a specific pattern.
Example:

```
Text
Text
Startpattern
print this line
Print this line
print this line
Endpattern
Text
Text
Text
```

Also the start pattern and the end pattern should be printed. My first try was not really successful:

```
my $LOGFILE = "/var/log/logfile";
my @array;
# open the file (or die trying)

open(LOGFILE) or die("Could not open log file.");
foreach $line () {
  if($line =~  m/Sstartpattern/i){
    print $line;
    foreach $line2 () {
      if(!$line =~  m/Endpattern/i){
        print $line2;
      }
    }
  }
}
close(LOGFILE);
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I know that deep down, when you wrote "Could not open log file.", you meant to write, "Could not open $LOGFILE: $!".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
#!perl -w
use strict;

my $spool = 0;
my @matchingLines;

while (<DATA>) {
    if (/StartPattern/i) {
        $spool = 1;
        next;
    }
    elsif (/Endpattern/i) {
        $spool = 0;
        print map { "$_ \n" } @matchingLines;
        @matchingLines = ();
    }
    if ($spool) {
        push (@matchingLines, $_);
    }
}

__DATA__

Text
Text
Startpattern
print this line
Print this line
print this line
Endpattern
Text
Text
Text
Startpattern
print this other line
Endpattern
```

If you want the start and end patterns to also be printed, add the push statements in that if block as well.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much. Now I have only one more problem :-) How can I set dynamic arraynames and print each array after I grabbed all matching lines into it?

Comment: I am fairly new to perl myself and I didn't quite understand the question. If you can explain in a little more detail on what your requirement is, I might be able to help.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the scalar [range operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators):

```
open my $fh, "<", $file or die $!;

while (<$fh>) {
    print if /Startpattern/ .. /Endpattern/;
}
```

Comment: Hi,that sounds pretty good but I have multiple groups with start and endpatterns.

Comment: @Tester: scalar `..` should work for any number of groups within the file

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
my $LOGFILE = "/var/log/logfile";
open my $fh, "<$LOGFILE" or die("could not open log file: $!");
my $in = 0;

while(<$fh>)
{
    $in = 1 if /Startpattern/i;
    print if($in);
    $in = 0 if /Endpattern/i;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately prints it only the line matching the startpattern. I need to print the startpattern, the text between the start and the endpattern and also the endpattern. I have multiple groups with startpattern,text,text,text,endpattern

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I forgot to delete a line. How can I group this entries into several arrays?

Comment: I am also working on similar stuff , but the solution mentioned by eugene-y  also printing startpattern and end pattern , which we dont want , how can we negate them, please suggest.